# Flink Job Cluster vs Session Cluster - deploying and configuration

Tags: java, docker, deployment, apache-flink, flink-streaming

I'm researching docker/k8s deployment possibilities for Flink 1.9.1.

I'm after reading/watching [1](https://youtu.be/w721NI-mtAA) [2](https://youtu.be/WeHuTRwicSw) [3](https://ci.apache.org/projects/flink/flink-docs-stable/ops/deployment/docker.html) [4](https://github.com/apache/flink/blob/release-1.9/flink-container/docker/README.md) [5](http://apache-flink-user-mailing-list-archive.2336050.n4.nabble.com/Flink-Job-claster-scalability-td32027.html).

Currently we do think that we will try go with Job Cluster approach although
we would like to know what is the community trend with this? We would rather
not deploy more than one job per Flink cluster.

Anyways, I was wondering about few things:

1. How can I change the number of task slots per task manager for Job and
   Session Cluster? In my case I'm running docker on VirtualBox where I have 4
   CPUs assigned to this machine. However each task manager is spawned with
   only one task slot for Job Cluster. With Session Cluster however, on the
   same machine, each task manager is spawned with 4 task slots.

   In both cases Flink's UI shows that each Task manager has 4 CPUs.
2. How can I resubmit job if I'm using a Job Cluster. I'm referring this use
   case [5](http://apache-flink-user-mailing-list-archive.2336050.n4.nabble.com/Flink-Job-claster-scalability-td32027.html). You may say that I have to start the job again but with different
   arguments. What is the procedure for this? I'm using checkpoints btw.
   Should I kill all task manager containers and rerun them with different parameters?
3. How I can resubmit job using Session Cluster?
4. How I can provide log config for Job/Session cluster?
   I have a case, where I changed log level and log format in log4j.properties
   and this is working fine on local (IDE) environment. However when I build
   the fat jar, and ran a Job Cluster based on this jar it seams that my log4j
   properties are not passed to the cluster. I see the original format and
   original (INFO) level.

Thanks,

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Currently we do think that we will try go with Job Cluster approach although we would like to know what is the community trend with this? We would rather not deploy more than one job per Flink cluster.

This question is probably better suited on the user mailing list.

> How can I change the number of task slots per task manager for Job and Session Cluster?

You can control this via the config option [taskmanager.numberOfTaskSlots](https://ci.apache.org/projects/flink/flink-docs-release-1.9/ops/config.html#taskmanager-numberoftaskslots)

> How I can resubmit job using Session Cluster?

This is described [here](https://ci.apache.org/projects/flink/flink-docs-release-1.9/ops/upgrading.html#restarting-streaming-applications). The bottom line is that you create a savepoint and resume your job from it. It is also possible to resume a job from [retained checkpoints](https://ci.apache.org/projects/flink/flink-docs-release-1.9/ops/state/checkpoints.html#resuming-from-a-retained-checkpoint).

> How can I resubmit job if I'm using a Job Cluster.

Conceptually, this is no different from resuming a job from a savepoint in a session cluster. You can specify the path to the savepoint as a command line argument to the cluster entrypoint. The details are described [here](https://github.com/apache/flink/blob/release-1.9/flink-container/kubernetes/README.md#resuming-from-a-savepoint).

> How I can provide log config for Job/Session cluster?

If you are using the scripts in the `bin/` directory of the Flink binary distribution to start your cluster (e.g., `bin/start-cluster.sh`, `bin/jobmanager.sh`, `bin/taskmanager.sh`, etc.), you can change the log4j configuration by adapting `conf/log4j.properties`. The logging configuration is passed to the JobManager and TaskManager JVMs as a system variable (see [`bin/flink-daemon.sh`](https://github.com/apache/flink/blob/7513d9b184feffdcb6e0c09d1b74f8de21a98e81/flink-dist/src/main/flink-bin/bin/flink-daemon.sh#L89)). See also the Chapter [*"How to use logging"*](https://ci.apache.org/projects/flink/flink-docs-release-1.9/monitoring/logging.html) in the Flink documentation.